# Python/xpath get instances of text in arbitrary element

Tags: python, xpath

Given the following:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>Text 1</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            Text 2
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <a href="#">Text 3</a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        ...
    </tr>
</table>
```

Given the above table, how would I extract all the text? Note that the number of nested elements is arbitrary so I can't just look for the first sibling, zero-th sibling, and second sibling.

I'm looking for a general way to extract the text.

```
In [1]: d="""<table>
   ...:     <tr>
   ...:         <td>
   ...:             <div>Text 1</div>
   ...:         </td>
   ...:         <td>
   ...:             Text 2
   ...:         </td>
   ...:         <td>
   ...:             <div>
   ...:                 <a href="#">Text 3</a>
   ...:             </div>
   ...:         </td>
   ...:     </tr>
   ...:     <tr>
   ...:         ...
   ...:     </tr>
   ...: </table>"""

In [3]: from lxml import etree

In [4]: f = etree.HTML(d)

In [5]: f.xpath('normalize-space(string(/table))')
Out[5]: ''

In [6]: f.xpath('normalize-space(string(//table))')
Out[6]: 'Text 1 Text 2 Text 3 ...
```

Comment: i think this will solve your problem //*[string-length(normalize-space(./text()))>0]/text()

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
normalize-space(string(/table))
```

Comment: @strimp099 nope, it's the root

Comment: Hmmm can you see my edit and tell me what I've done wrong such that the text is not picked up with `/table`?